# Manipulating a Storyboard's target object

Tags: animation, silverlight-3.0, storyboard

In the handler for the `Completed` event of a `Storyboard`, how do i get the element that the storyboard was being applied to?

My Storyboard is part of an ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="Container" Height="30" >
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeOut" BeginTime="0:0:7"  Completed="FadeOut_Completed">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:3" Storyboard.TargetName="Container" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Grid.Resources>

                [...snip...]

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

in the `Completed` event i want to grab the grid called *Container* so that i can do nasty things with its DataContext. Can this be done, or am i going about it the wrong way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is that it is not possible - not in Silverlight 3 anyway.

Using a debugger i was able to find a private property of the Storyboard that when i walked it up the object tree i got to the containing template item - however i couldn't touch this from code using reflection due to the security restrictions placed upon silverlight apps (this may well be possible in WPF though).

My eventual solution involved using a `Dictionary<Storyboard, Grid>`, and a couple of event handlers. With the template i attached a `Loaded` handler, this means my handler gets called everytime an instance of the template is created and loaded (i.e. for every data item that is bound to the listbox). At this point, i have a reference to the physical instance of the template, so i can search its children for the storyboard:

```
private void ItemTemplate_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard s = getStoryBoard(sender);
    if (s != null)
    {
        if (!_startedStoryboards.ContainsKey(s))
            _startedStoryboards.Add(s, (Grid)sender);
    }
}

private Storyboard getStoryBoard(object container)
{
    Grid g = container as Grid;
    if (g != null)
    {
        if (g.Resources.Contains("FadeOut"))
        {
            Storyboard s = g.Resources["FadeOut"] as Storyboard;
            return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private Dictionary<Storyboard, Grid> _startedStoryboards = new Dictionary<Storyboard, Grid>();
```

Then when the storyboard's `Completed` event is fired, i can easily use this dictionary as a lookup to retrieve the item template it was hosted within, and from there i can get the `DataContext` of the item template and do the nasty things i planned:

```
private void FadeOut_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_startedStoryboards.ContainsKey((Storyboard)sender))
    {
        Grid g = _startedStoryboards[(Storyboard)sender];
        if (g.DataContext != null)
        {
            MyDataItem z = g.DataContext as MyDataItem;

            if (z != null)
            {
                ... do my thing ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*[Note: this code has been sanitized for public viewing, excuse any small discrepancies or syntactical errors you may spot]*